# Append html to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and want to show them in new lines. I'm trying to append the `inputs[i]` but it's not writing anything, but it shows the `console.log` correctly. `.panel-body` is referring to the div within `testCaseAccordion` above.

```
var inputs = testCase.params.split(',');

testCaseAccordion += '<div id="collapse-' + testCase.name + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"></div></div>';

for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
  $('.panel-body').append(inputs[i] + '</br>');
}
```

Comment: Does `$('.panel-body')` exist?

Comment: The code you've shown works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/wjLs5arg/. Please check the console for errors. It would also help us to diagnose any issues if we could see what the value of `testCase.params` is

Comment: what is your inputs string looks like?

Comment: what is testCaseAccordion???

Comment: it's generated above @FrankerZ in the console I only see :before :after in the html

Comment: Are you sure you're not appending hidden items? Any CSS associated with classes `panel-collapse` `collapse` that could hide your items?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append to an HTML string, using jQuery. `$` will match elements in the current DOM. It has no knowledge of the previous string (`testCaseAccordion`), as it has not been added to the DOM yet. At the current point you're trying to use `$`, the html is nothing more than a string in a variable.

You're much better off working with nodes directly. You can create/append nodes dynamically like so:

```
//Init testCaseAccordian as a NODE, or feel free to grab it directly from the dom (ie. $('#accordion'))
var testCaseAccordion = $('<div />');

var inputs = testCase.params.split(',');

var panel = $('<div id="collapse-' + testCase.name + '" class="panel-collapse collapse" />');

//Initialize the body, and append it to the panel.
var panelBody = $('<div class="panel-body" />');
panel.append(panelBody);

//Loop through the inputs, and add all the inputs to each panelBody, followed by a <br />
for(var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
  $(panelBody).append(inputs[i]).append($('<br />'));
}

//Finally add the panel to the accordion
$(testCaseAccordion).append(panel);

//If testCaseAccordion is already in the DOM, you can skip the following line, otherwise you need to add the entire testCaseAccordion somewhere.
$('body').append(testCaseAccordion);
```